# Least resource way to animate curve line at D3 library

Tags: javascript, animation, path, d3.js, bezier

Does D3 has built-in method to animate drawing of curve line?
I need a lot of animation curves in my project. I have tried Jason Davies solution [**link to example**](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/), [**link to js file**](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/animated-bezier.js), and it's working fine, but even Chrome browser begins to lagging after 30+ animate curves at one time.
In my case each curve has own coordinates, so browser should process the path for all of them, I am understand this, but Jason's solution recalculates all the path at every iteration, as I understood that was done for ability to dinamically change path via gray dots.
I'm new to d3 library so I can not realize, is it possible to calculate all path once, and then simply animate curve drawing from 0% to 100% ? Or everything is even easier and there are 
simple method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the path's `d` parameter will animate with d3's default animation. So this should animate properly:

```
var svg = d3.select('#myelement').append('svg'),
    curve = svg.append('path')
                 .attr('d', 'M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200S400,300 400,200');

curve.transition()
       .attr('d', 'M0,0 C100,100 250,100 250,200S400,300 400,200');
```

See this on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x22xE/).

For additional documentation on the curve commands, see [the official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCurveCommands).

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to add, this should be Bezier curve, like Davies sample

Comment: Is there any possibility to use the path element an cubic/quadratic bezier commands? http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands

Answer (score 3):

A cheap and simple way to animate a Bezier curve using d3.js is to transition the `stroke-dasharray` property. The idea is to start off with the entire line being a single gap, and end off with the line being a single dash.

See this jsfiddle for a simple implementation of this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/nj37gkgq/